# Github references reported as outdated by NPM

Tags: github, npm

When referencing a github repository within `package.json` like this:

```
"my-package": "https://user:password@github.com/user-name/my-package.git"
```

Command `npm outdated` produces the following:

```
Package                            Current   Wanted   Latest  Location
my-package                         1.0.0      git      git    screener
```

Is there a way in that reference syntax to specify a version? And if not, is there a way to make NPM suppress reporting the package as outdated?

---

Tested with Node.js v12.6.0 and NPM v6.9.0

Comment: What npm version are you using?

Comment: @JLewkovich Just added ;)

Comment: Only suggestion I have is changing the url to `https://user:password@github.com/user-name/my-package.git#master` and perhaps that will work. Make sure you delete your `node_modules` folder and rerun `npm install` before running `npm outdated` again

Comment: I've just found out that forcing NPM to reinstall the package helps, and it also changed the URL from `https://` to `git+https://`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package.json documentation mentions in the [Git URLs as Dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)

> Git urls are of the form:
>
> ```
> <protocol>://[<user>[:<password>]@]<hostname>[:<port>][:][/]<path>[#<commit-ish> | #semver:<semver>]
> ```
>
> `<protocol>` is one of `git`, `git+ssh`, `git+http`, `git+https`, or `git+file`.

That could explain the "`Wanted git`" part of the error message.